# MATLAB GUI doesn't respond when my codes are running

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm using `MATLAB R2014b`. I designed a `GUI` that have a loop using `parallel computing`. First I will set the number of loops in this `GUI` and my program will start. Suppose that I want stop the program in middle of process. I should press `CONTROL+C` to stop `MATLAB`. I put a button to stop it and call a function in loop but it doesn't work when my program is running. These isn't any respond to this button when my program is running.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I presume by "parallel computing" you mean that your code is running is running in a `parfor` loop. The `parfor` loop is a synchronous construct which does not allow any other MATLAB commands to execute. If you wish to allow interactive use via a GUI, you need to use [`parfeval`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/parfeval.html) instead. [This example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/examples/parfeval-blackjack.html) shows how you can terminate parallel processing early.

One thing to bear in mind when using `parfeval` is that each call you make to that is a remote invocation, so you need to divide your problem into "sensible" sized chunks.